# Understanding the ramp-up time in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am getting started with JMeter and I wish to understand the functionality of the ramp-up period in it.
I set up a basic test for accessing a website and wanted to check the maximum number of users it could receive without crashing.

I set the following properties in the JMeter:

1. Number of threads(users) = 100;
2. Ramp-up period(seconds) = 10;
3. Loop count = 1;

**Expected result:**
I was hoping that the JMeter would virtually send 100 users in 10 seconds and the test would be finished in those 10 seconds as well

**Actual result:**
The test always took more than 10 seconds

**Question:**
What I don't understand here is, what does it mean when I set the said period to 10 seconds? Is the test bound to finish in 10 seconds or it will try its best to finish as soon as possible depending upon my internet connection,processor etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like this,
In your script, thread count would be the number of users. In your case, it's 100 users. Then the Ramp-up is the total time you give for all the threads to be active. In your case, 10s does not mean the test should end in 10 seconds. But all the 100 threads should have stared sending requests. Simply ramp-up does not have to do anything with the test execution time.

Let's take some examples :

- Test 1 - Threads - 100, Ramp-up - 0 > At the beginning of the tests 100 Threads are active
- Test 1 - Threads - 100, Ramp-up - 1 > 100 threads will be active in 1s
- Test 3 - Threads - 100, Ramp-up - 2 > Within 1s > 50 threads active, in the 2s next 50 will be active

As you can see, The number of threads to be active in a second is **Threads/Ramp-up**. The total test execution time will depend on the factors like,

- Number of requests per thread group
- Server performance
- You connection speed
- The type of test you are planning to execute

Based on the above factors, the test execution time can vary between milliseconds and hours.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It means that 100 users will ramp up in 10 seconds.
100/10=10 means in 1 second there will be 10 users, next second 10 users, so at the end of 2 seconds, 20 users will be active on the site.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but can you please explain why the run time exceeds 10 seconds; the test runs for 15-20 seconds to send 100 users. Is this due to my internet connection and processor or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup means that:

1. JMeter will add 10 users each second for 10 seconds
2. Each user will start executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as fast as it can
3. It means that last user will start on 10th second and the total duration of the test will depend on:

   - the number of Samplers and [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)
   - your application response time

It might also be the case you will be conducting much less load than you expect due to this `1` iteration as it means that when a thread (virtual user) doesn't have any Samplers to execute it will be shut down so you may run into the situation when 1st sampler have already finished its work and is shut down and the last one hasn't yet been started. See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article for more information.

You can see how may virtual users where active using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener

Comment: Thank you for these comments and the shared links, they were very useful!

Comment: What happens if there is a loop of two (2) assigned to this thread group? Does that mean that after the 10th second, the same incremental 10-user requests will take place till 20th second? In other word, we'll have 10-user threads making requests every second, up to 20 seconds? Or after the 10th seconds, since all the threads are still active, the 11th second, we'll have 100 users making requests over and over again till 20th second?